# How To Access Form Element Value Of Dynamic Generated Select List That's Hidden On Init

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have dynamically generated `<select>` lists being written to a default visible |div| and a hidden |div| in my HTML.

```
<div id="Tab1">
  <select id="img">
    <option value="1">My Img</option>
  </select>
  <button onclick="passSelectedValue('file')" />
</div>

<div id="Tab2" class="hidden">
  <select id="parent_page">
    <option value="2">My Page</option>
  </select>
  <button onclick="passSelectedValue('page')" />
</div>
```

When it's made visible by the user and the user makes a selection and clicks the button, I can't retrieve the selected value, it's returning a NULL value. I've read the articles on delegation but I'm not sure if I'm approaching this correctly. My first |div| that is visible after the page loads, I can access that value without issue. Note that I'm only generating the |select| lists in the |divs|, the button is hard coded into the page. When I click the button and it fires the function with "page" as the argument, everything works execept the value of the select element returns NULL. I'm thinking that my select list that's in the hidden |div| isn't registered in the DOM? How do I get the |select| list in the hidden |div| to register and be accessible?

```
function passSelectedValue(argForm){
    var my_value = '';
    if (argForm=='file') {
        my_value = document.getElementById('img').value;
    };
    if (argForm=='page') {
        my_value = document.getElementById('parent_page').value;
    };      
    setFormValue(my_value,argForm);
};
```

Comment: You're testing on IE<9?

Comment: How you populate the second select?

Comment: @Teemu I'm testing using Chrome 47...

Comment: @Lipsyor I'm writing the |select| list from my database using PHP. My button is hard coded into the HTML so that why it's working partially (i.e. firing the function but not accessing the value).

Comment: It's a little bit strange but... may you test with
`<button onclick="passSelectedValue('page')">Click me</button>`
instead of
`<button onclick="passSelectedValue('page')" />`

Comment: Thanks but that's not my issue. The code works, I'm just not able to access the value of the form element in the hidden |div|. I'm not doing any page refreshes or anything, I'm writing all the needed markup to the HTML page.

Comment: Although is not your issue, note that correct use of button is not with slefclosed tag.
Second div shoud be registered in DOM, because it is created server side.
I'm triyng to replicate, but it works fine for me. I'm testing with `visibility: hidden;` and with `display: none;`. How is your hidden class?

Answer (score 0):

You can not retrieve the value of a selectbox in the same way you do with an inputfield.

You need to do this in this way:

```
var selectBox = document.getElementById('img');
var my_value = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;
```

Comment: Thanks. I've made this adjustment but I'm still getting a null value on execution. I'm thinking it's because the |select| element in the hidden div isn't registering....

Comment: This has nothing to do with the hidden element. Something might be wrong in your code. I haven't checked because in your question you say you are getting 'null' as value, and this is because you are using the wrong method for doing this and I have only corrected it. Any reason why you don't use jQuery for this?

Comment: thanks. I rewrote it in jQuery and it solved my issue. Thanks for your willingness to assist. Thank you.